# Why am I not able to add the tensors together?

Tags: python, keras

I am currently implementing RCL layers which is defined on [this page](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3faa/be9428e76ac96af6d81a34cfe0a823e947af.pdf).

```
import keras
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import merge, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Input
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K

#   RCL:
#   BatchNorm(Relu(conv(L-1) + conv(L)))
#

def make_RCNN(dim_1,dim_2,dim_3,number_of_rcl,num_of_filter, filtersize):
    return True

def RCL(feed_forward_input,num_of_filter, filtersize):
    conv = Conv2D(filters=num_of_filter, kernel_size=filtersize)
    recurrent_input = conv(feed_forward_input)
    merged = merge([feed_forward_input,recurrent_input],mode='sum')
    conv_relu = Relu(merged)
    conv_relu_batchnorm = BatchNormalization()(conv_relu)
    return conv_relu_batchnorm

input = Input(shape=(30,30,3))
output = RCL(feed_forward_input=input,num_of_filter=3,filtersize=3)
```

and I am getting error message:

```
python RCNN.py 
Using TensorFlow backend.
Couldn't import dot_parser, loading of dot files will not be possible.
RCNN.py:22: UserWarning: The `merge` function is deprecated and will be removed after 08/2017. Use instead layers from `keras.layers.merge`, e.g. `add`, `concatenate`, etc.
  merged = merge([feed_forward_input,recurrent_input],mode='sum')
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py:460: UserWarning: The `Merge` layer is deprecated and will be removed after 08/2017. Use instead layers from `keras.layers.merge`, e.g. `add`, `concatenate`, etc.
  name=name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RCNN.py", line 28, in <module>
    output = RCL(feed_forward_input=input,num_of_filter=3,filtersize=3)
  File "RCNN.py", line 22, in RCL
    merged = merge([feed_forward_input,recurrent_input],mode='sum')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py", line 460, in merge
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py", line 111, in __init__
    node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py", line 155, in _arguments_validation
    'Layer shapes: %s' % input_shapes)
ValueError: Only layers of same output shape can be merged using sum mode. Layer shapes: [(None, 30, 30, 3), (None, 28, 28, 3)]
```

It says that the shape is not the same... Which indeed is a problem, which only can be caused be a misunderstanding of the RCL..

But from what i understand, also defined here

[image: RCN explanation]

What i've implemented is a RCL that takes in a tensor that from a previous layer (feed forward tensor),  and apply a convolution on that tensor (reccurent tensor), These two tensor make the first and the second part of the z_ijk(t) equation. After this is the sum of both tensor computed, like according to the equation, which is where the function have some problems making sense as the the convoluted feed forward input = the recurrent input don't have the same size.. so how shall sum two tensor, when their size isn't the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution may just be as simple as adding a `padding='same'` argument to the Conv2D call, so the RCL method looks like this:

```
def RCL(feed_forward_input,num_of_filter, filtersize):
    conv = Conv2D(filters=num_of_filter, kernel_size=filtersize, padding='same')
    recurrent_input = conv(feed_forward_input)
    merged = merge([feed_forward_input,recurrent_input], mode='sum')
    conv_relu = relu(merged)
    conv_relu_batchnorm = BatchNormalization()(conv_relu)
    return conv_relu_batchnorm
```

Without it, the Conv2D layer resizes the input to a (28, 28, 3) image, which can't be merged with the original image. The padding parameter pads the image with zeros so the output has the same shape (or a simple fraction of the same shape) as the input.

Comment: That does fix it... but if it actually is the right solution I am not sure..  the paper doesn't mention anything related to padding.. So this is kind of a dirty fix...

Comment: Padding is a standard technique for convolution networks, and the paper may not bother to mention it. The error suggests that the convolution layer is resizing the input tensor to (28, 28, 3), which happens because the convolution filter has size 3x3, and as it strides across the image, it can only produce 28 distinct outputs (without it sliding off the edge of the image). Padding just adds a margin of zeros around the outside so that the input and output can have the same size. [This](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#convolutional-layer) explains it well.